# Adding labels outside d3 pie chart not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add labels in a d3 pie as displayed at http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799 but it is always displays the labels inside the slices.

```
    var dataset = ${pieList};

    var width = 700,
            height = 700,
            outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
            innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,

            innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
            innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius * .45,
            color = d3.scale.category20()    
            ;

    var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
            .append("svg:svg")              
            .data([dataset])                   
            .attr("width", width)           
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("svg:g")                
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")    
            ;

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()              
            .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);


    var arcFinal = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
    var arcFinal3 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()          
            .value(function (d) {
                return d.measure;
            });    

    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")    
            .data(pie)                          
            .enter()                            
            .append("svg:g")               
            .attr("class", "slice")    
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mouseout", mouseout)
            .on("click", up)
            ;

    arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color(i);
            }) 
            .attr("d", arc)    
            .append("svg:title") 
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.data.category + ": " + formatAsPercentage(d.data.measure);
            });

    d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .delay(10)
            .attr("d", arcFinal)
            ;


    arcs.filter(function (d) {
        return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2;
    })
            .append("svg:text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
            })


            .text(function (d) {
                return d.data.category;   
            })
            ;

            .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d)
                + ")rotate(" + angle(d)
                + ")translate(" + 700 + ",0)";
    })

    function angle(d) {
        var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
        return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
    }



    // Pie chart title          
    vis.append("svg:text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Attendance report 2015")
            .attr("class", "title")
            ;

    function mouseover() {
        d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(750)
                //.attr("stroke","red")
                //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                .attr("d", arcFinal3)
                ;
    }

    function mouseout() {
        d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(750)
                //.attr("stroke","blue")
                //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                .attr("d", arcFinal)
                ;
    }

    function up(d, i) {

        /* update bar chart when user selects piece of the pie chart */
        //updateBarChart(dataset[i].category);
        updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));
        updateLineChart(d.data.category, color(i));

    }
```

I want to display the labels outside of the pie slices but it always display inside the slices.

Comment: So what's your question? You already have a working example.

Comment: I want to display the labels outside the slices as displayed in the chart at http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799, but it is inside the slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to translate your text outward by the radius of the pie, which might be easiest to do after the rotate. So, something like:

```
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) 
    + ")rotate(" + angle(d) 
    + ")translate(" + radius + ",0)";
})
```

Where `radius` is the radius of your pie chart. Sometimes you might want to translate a few pixels further, so that you have a margin between the chart and the label.

This is certainly not the only answer, here are some more issues to watch out for though:

1. Rotating your text can end up with it being upside down on one side of the graph, which is not very readable.
2. After fixing the rotation issue, you might find that your label's `textanchor` causes long labels to go over the graph anyway.
3. If your pie slices are thin, you can end up writing labels over one another.

Comment: I added the function but now pie chart is not appearing. I have also posted the complete script.

Comment: This was intended to replace your previous transform on the labels. The underlying problem is that you are translating to arcFinal.centroid(d), which is the middle of the pie slice, and leaving it there. So you need to work out a transform to move your text outwards.

Comment: Now the labels are out of slices but no polylines.